# Updating android database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have like 400 records on my database, suppose this is the first version of my application. In the next version I added like more 15 records, and changed 20 of the 400 already there. In this case, do I need to change the version of the database? and if so, do I need to do something in `onUpgrade()` function or just change the commands where i'm inserting and everything will be fine?

Thank you.

Comment: Only some of the records fields change and added more records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you have a database with pre-filled records. Is the DB updatable by users? If not, you can just ship the new database file in the upgraded APK and be done with it. If the app logic allows for user-driven database changes, you cannot throw away the old one on upgrade. You'll have to keep track of preset record changes, keep the installed database version somewhere (i. e. in preferences), and upgrade the records when the app is upgraded. Also, you might have to deal with schema changes.

Comment: The database is not updatable by users, only by me. and the schema is not changed at all, and I'm like want to delete all the previous data and them all again.

Comment: Just ship a fresh file with an update. If it's copied from assets to a data folder, copy the file over when upgrading.

Comment: I'm inserting the data (written in code/ not from file) with boolean shared preferences for first time visit of the application, can I only set that boolean to default value on upgrade? and change the database version on upgrade.

Comment: Detect upgrade, delete all records, insert the actual ones (as if installing anew). In general, in the long run, incremental database updating tends to get out of control. Since your app lets you get away without that, take advantage.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm planning to do (delete then insert), but onUpgrade will be called if I only change the database version? Note that inserting takes time, so I only want to do it first time I open the application, I can't delete and insert each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update()
```

is called when you change already existed columns data.

```
onUpgrade()
```

is called when the structure of your table is changed. for example if you add a column.